# LWC Does not show additional fields in components

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

[image: Additional fields not displayed]

**HTML CODE**

```
    <!--POSM Item details : -->
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="lookupCmp">Search POSM Item</label>
    <c-lookup-lwc objectname="POSM_Item__c" iconname="standard:POSM_Item__c" onselected = {handleSelected}></c-lookup-lwc>
    <template if:true={POSM_Item__c}>
        <div class="demo-only" style="width: 30rem;">
            <article class="slds-tile">
                <h3 class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate" title="POSM Item details"><a href="javascript:void(0);">POSM Item details</a></h3>
                <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                    <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
                        <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Name">Name :</dt>
                        <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Record Name">{POSM_Item__c.Name}</dd>
                        <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Id">Id:</dt>
                        <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Record Id">{POSM_Item__c.Id}</dd>
                        <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Image">Image :</dt>
                        <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Record Image">{POSM_Item__c.POSM_Image__c}</dd>
                        <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Brand">Brand :</dt>
                        <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Record Brand">{POSM_Item__c.Brand__c}</dd>
                        <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Item">Item :</dt>
                        <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Record Item Code">{POSM_Item__c.Item_Code__c}</dd>
                        
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </template>


</lightning-card>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class LookupDemo extends LightningElement {
    @track
    POSM_Item__c;
        handleSelected(event) {
            var objectname = event.detail.ObjectName;
            if( objectname === "POSM_Item__c") {
                    this.POSM_Item__c = {Name : event.detail.Name, Id: event.detail.Id, Image : event.detail.POSM_Image__c, Brand : event.detail.Brand__c, Item : event.detail.Item_Code__c}

            }
        }
}
```

**Lookup Apex Controller**

```
/**
 *@description : Class to query data based on passed object and searchterm
 *@param objectName :  Object name for lookup
 *@param searchFor : search term
 */
public with sharing class LookupController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Object> getRecordsByName(String objectName, String searchFor) {
        String queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name, POSM_Image__c, Brand__c, Item_Code__c FROM ';
        queryString += String.escapeSingleQuotes(objectName) + ' WHERE Name Like \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchFor) + '%\'';
        return Database.query(queryString);
    }
}
```

for some reason the image, brand and item fields are not being populated. anyone knows why?

the field types are Image: Rich Text Box, Brand: Picklist and Item: Text

Let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: How are you establishing your connection to `getRecordsByName`?

Comment: Does the user running this code has necessary FLS on those fields?

Comment: @JayantDas the user is an Admin user

Comment: How are you calling the Apex method from your LWC? Also is the Apex correct - the return type for `Database.query` is `List<SObject>` whereas yours shows `List<Object>`?

Comment: @JayantDas i changed it to List<SObject> it still does not display the other fields

Comment: It’s still not clear when/how are you calling that method from your LWC